# Is "sich zu Wort melden" a formal phrase?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I came across this phrase for the first time, several times in the same novel. 
Is it much different from sich melden? Is it a more formal phrase?

Comment: [What does](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=sich%20zu%20Wort%20melden&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) [your dictionary](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=sich+zu+Wort+melden&l=deen&in=&lf=de) [say](http://www.dict.cc/?s=sich+zu+Wort+melden)? Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

It’s used in different contexts, as crx explained.

> sich zu Wort melden

→ means more or less *to raise your voice*. It’s connected to a public environment, e.g. a discussion, a presentation (if someone raises a hand and asks a question), etc. Can also used in a more abstract context, e.g. if a politician or an organisation joins a public discussion via newspapers. It is strongly connected to having an opinion.

> sich melden

→ is either used in an informal context: if you call/write someone to tell that person you are “there”. “There” could be, e.g. at a meeting point, out of your business meeting and ready to go to lunch, or simply alive and wanting to say hi.

The other use is in class, when a student raises his or her hand. 
It can also mean that gesture in a context like the presentation mentioned above, but than it’s more neutral than *sich zu Wort melden*.

> Während des Vortrags meldete sich Herr Müller zu Wort.

→ Mr. Müller has an opinion he wants to share, probably he disagrees with the speaker

> Während des Vortrags meldete sich Herr Müller

→ Mr. Müller could have anything to say, maybe just a question, or maybe a flaming speech, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

From my native speaker view I would say "sich melden" means something like "Hey, here I am. You might give me the word" and "sich zu Wort melden" means "I am here and say. I want to enter the discussion". So both are similar but the second one is more firm.